# Get the Read and Write Speed of a Flash Drive

Tags: c++, file-transfer, usb-drive, rate, measure

How can I find out the reading and writing transfer rate of an usb flash drive? I wonder if there is a way to get this without copying a large file and measuring the time. Even if I had to do that, what file size and content would give me a representable result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use an already available tool for this. Here are a few that I found 
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-lightweight-tools-to-check-the-speed-of-your-usb-flash-drive-windows/

Comment: I needed that for my own program. Based on the applications linked by you I could figure out how to implement what I need. Thanks.